# how to add a new option in the second position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a new option in a select.
Using this piece of script I can add a new option, but it comes in the last position. I would like to show it in the second position after the first option.

```
$("#mySelect").append(new Option("option text", "0"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the first option element using `:eq(0)` or `:first` along with `.after()` to add content as next sibling:

```
$("#mySelect option:first").after(new Option("option text", "0"));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5n6scmb/)**